Is it really mutating through a filter_view::iterator in a single pass only not that bad?
I recently watched Nico Josuttis's Keynote Meeting C++ 2022, and just finished reading the Barry Revzin's post about that same topic.
The code in question is this
// increment even elements:
for (int& i : coll | std::views::filter(isEven)) {
    ++i; // UB: but works
}

My question is (maybe for compiler writers), how far is my imagination going, if I think that the UB mandated by [range.filter.iterator]/1 could make the following code,
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

constexpr auto isEven = [](int i){
    return i % 2 == 0;
};

bool bar();

bool foo() {
    bool b = bar();
    std::vector<int> coll{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    if (b)
        for (int& i : coll | std::views::filter(isEven))
            ++i; // UB: but works
    return b;
}

be compiled down to just return false;, i.e. to this?
foo():
        xor     eax, eax
        ret

I mean, the compiler does see that there's at least one element in coll that satisfies isEven, which means that if b is true and the for loop therefore runs, ++i would rund, which would lead to UB. Hence the compiler could happily conclude that bar() must return false.
Is such "reasoning" entirely impossible for a compiler?

"// UB: but works" - an unfortunate consequence of UB is that it may appear to work - that's unfortunately part of the set of anything being acceptable. But, code with UB does not work. There's no guarantee that a recompile with a different compiler, new minor release of the same compiler or a minor change to compiler options won't generate entirety different behaviour. Code that works does so all the time, in any situation. Code with UB is just broken and you can't have any expectations about what it will do - that's not how I like the code I write to behave.

Interesting note in Barry's blogpost: "This is, per the wording of the standard library, undefined behavior. - But this example is… fine. It’s going to work as expected. We’re doing a single pass through the elements, so even though we’re doing the bad kind of mutation (changing our elements from satisfying the predicate to not), there’s no place for our algorithm (the for loop) to get into a wacky state."

They should fix std::views::filter.

The reason you should never trust UB is that you are lying to the compiler.  You have promised to the compiler that you won't do anything undefined, and it relies on your promise when it makes optimization decisions (particularly decisions based on data flow analysis).  The issue isn't how the compiler might implement a particular bit of UB, it's how the compiler might optimize around it.

@Craig, yes, but in a case like this, the lie is harmless if the compiler can't leverage that knowledge anyway. The simple fact that the standard says "this is UB" doesn't mean anything until you pick a compiler and see what assembly it generates for that code. And how it does that depends on the decision some human has taken.

So it definitely can't compile down to what you showed, because it needs to at least call bar(). Can a standard library implementation annotate this into core-language UB? Probably. Will one? I'd be very surprised.

I would agree that you can get away with it in a simple case where there isn't anything that the compiler might gain with dataflow analysis, especially at low optimization levels where the compiler doesn't try to do such analysis anyway.  I would argue that the places where that might come into play at high optimization levels are not as obvious as you might think.

@Craig, what I'm saying is that there's no inherent reason why modifying an element that satisfies the filter in such a way that it doesn't satisfy it should do anything bad. It's not like accessing an array out of bounds. So unless the compiler developer intentionally takes advantage of that in their compiler, nothing bad will happen.

My main concern for something like this would be data movement e.g. if there were another reference to an element that was modified, the compiler might assume it was unchanged.  I also think it's theoretically possible that an extreme compiler might go to a version of what you suggested, except including the call to bar since it might have side effects.  This sort of possibility is difficult because even the compiler isn't sophisticated enough to make that deduction now, you can't be sure that will be the case in the future.
